# Different access permissions for different classes in C++

Tags: oop, visual-c++

I have a question about access permissions.

I am writing a version of Game Of Life in C++ (Object-Oriented).
The part where I need help features three classes:

- The Storage class is used to store cells in an array. This array, of course, is private and the class has public methods for setting the LifeState of cells and return the LifeState of a cell.
- The Manager class is supposed to manage the cells which basically means it is the only class that should be able to access the SetCell method.
- The Neighbourfinder class is where it gets interesting for me: it should be able to use the ReturnCell method of Storage in order to find the living Neighbours of a cell but not the SetCell method.

I could make SetCell private and Manager a friend class of Storage but that would also mean that the Manager could directly access the Array, which is something i don't want.
To make it short:

One class has an Array and two methods. Each of the methods should be accessible to a different class than the other and no class should be allowed to access the array.
I hope this was understandable and will not be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Storage` and `Manager` classes are almost always a bad idea. Your design is causing your coding problems. `Neighbourfinder` is another class that follows the "verb-er" pattern, and probably an equally bad idea.

Instead, the primary class you want is `Board`. It knows the board rules, that's why it's called `Board`. Hence, `Board::SetCell` is `private`. The `Board::nextRound()` method can be public.

I could also see a `Board::countLiveNeighbours` method, but that can be `private` too since that's only needed in the implementation of `nextRound`.

Comment: @Wilsu: No, `nextRound` updates the board to the next state. It doesn't output it. Outputting requires either a new method (in which case `Board::GetCell` can be private) or a new function outside `Board` (in which case `GetCell must be public).

Comment: @Wilsu: The SRP actually means that the cells and the rules for the cells belong together. The cells should probably be stored in a `std::vector<std::vector<Cell>>`  though, and the SRP says `Board`  shouldn't be dealing with `new[]`. That is the responsibility of `vector< >`

Comment: Accidentally deleted my comment, sorry. Alright, thank you for your help.